# How to start a nuxt 3 project on a specific IP Address

Tags: npm, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nitro

I am currently transferring a Nuxt 2 project over to Nuxt 3.
The server I use has a fixed IP address on which the application runs.

In Nuxt 2 there were the following options in nuxt.config.js in which I could assign the appropriate IP address:

```
servers: {
 host: process.env.NUXT_DAEMON_IP,
 port: '3000' // optional
}
```

However, in Nuxt 3, this option is no longer supported.

Where and how can I store these options in Nuxt 3?
Do I have to do this via the nitro options?

Answer (score 1):

For production, you can specify your env variables as:

`NITRO_HOST` or `HOST`
`NITRO_PORT` or `PORT`

Documentation: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#configuring-defaults-at-runtime

For development, you can use the following code in nuxt.config.js:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devServer: {
    host: ...,
    port: ...
  },
  // ...
})
```

Documentation: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#devserver

Comment: For me devServer never works. Nuxt 3.7.0 with Nitro 2.6.2

Comment: @maestroosram To be honest, I answered following the docs, but I haven't tested it since I never needed to change host or port. BTW, when I replayed, we were still with Nuxt 3.6.5

Answer (score 1):

In Nuxt 3, you can set the server host and port using the `nitro` configuration file.

Create a `.nitro` folder in your project root directory, if it doesn't exist already. In the `.nitro` folder, create a file named `config.yml`.

In your `config.yml` file, add the following lines to specify the desired IP address and port number:

```yaml
server:
  host: <your-ip-address>
  port: <port-number>
```

Replace `<your-ip-address>` with the actual IP address of your server and `<port-number>` with the port number on which you want to run your application.

After setting these options, start your Nuxt 3 project using the `nitro dev` command.

Note that `nitro` provides many other configuration options for your Nuxt 3 project. You can learn more about them by visiting the official `nitro` documentation.

Thanks.